# Best practice for remote compilation and test?

Tags: testing, ssh, makefile

For some reason, I need to compile and test my project on a remote server.

One solution I use is [ssh + make](http://linuxgazette.net/issue21/sshmake.html), this is the `r_makefile` script I currently use

```
# usage: make -f r_makefile
all.remote: a.remote b.remote makefile.remote

%.remote: %.c
    scp $< remotehost:~/work/test
    touch $@

makefile.remote: makefile
    scp $< remotehost:~/work/test
    touch $@

test: all.remote
    ssh remotehost 'cd work/test && make test'
```

And the `makefile`.

```
CC = gcc
objects = a.o b.o
a: $(objects)
    $(CC) $(objects) -o a

a.o: a.c
b.o: b.c

test: a
    ./a
```

It works fine for me now, but I have to keep track of both `makefile` and `r_makefile`. As the code grows(which makes my `makefile` more complicated), it becomes hard to modify the `r_makefile`.

I wonder if there is a tool could do this for me, or automatically generate the `r_makefile`. I currently use git for version control.

What is the best practice for remote compilation and test, is there another way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just `rsync` the whole directory and then `ssh <host> make ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice for remote tests is using [DejaGnu](http://www.gnu.org/s/dejagnu/). The project is (understated) a little scarce on documentation, but quite powerful, and supports remote tests out of the box.